# adjusting x-axis in R histograms

Tags: r, plot, histogram

This histogram is really ugly:

```
hist(rbinom(10000, 20000, 0.0001),freq=F,right=F)
```

I don't want spaces between my bars. I tried different `breaks=` methods but they all produce similar results. Any ideas?

I also want each bin value (or mean values )to be printed under the **center** of it's bar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a way to center the labels:

```
x <- rbinom(1000, 2000, 0.001)
tmp <- hist(x, breaks=0:(max(x)+1), xaxt="n", right=FALSE, freq=FALSE)
axis(1, at=tmp$mids, labels=0:max(x))
```

Comment: +1 nice and simple, although the `breaks=0:(max(x)+1)` is not generic enough (in some cases you would like binning and not a bar for each int)

Comment: This was just an example, it could be easily replaced by an appropriate `seq` statement.

Answer (score 4):

if the values are integer and simply you want to count up them, how about

```
barplot(table(rbinom(10000, 20000, 0.0001)))
```

Comment: that's good for some cases, but sometimes you'd really want the values to be binned together

Answer (score 2):

In such a case I usually use:

```
 hist(rbinom(1000,2000,0.0001),breaks=function(x) length(unique(x)))
```

Comment: +1 thanks, that solves the first part. any suggestions on how to make the x labels centered?

Answer (score 0):

Also:

```
x <- rbinom(10000, 20000, 0.0001)
hist(x, br = seq(-0.01, max(x)+1, 1), freq=F, col="black")
```

(the `col="black"` is not necessary, of course, I just find it more readeable in black!)